# Customizing x-axis for Tornado chart in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

How can i set the single start point for two mirror axis? I have built a graph with 'make_subplot' function. But I get an empty space in the center. I use the 'Sample Superstore' dataset from [Tableau data collection](https://public.tableau.com/app/learn/sample-data).

My code:

```
df_oct = df.loc[(df['order_date'] > '2017-09-30') & (df['order_date'] < '2017-11-01') & (df['region'] == 'Central')]
df_sep = df.loc[(df['order_date'] > '2017-08-31') & (df['order_date'] < '2017-10-01') & (df['region'] == 'Central')]

states = pd.DataFrame(
            df.loc[(df['order_date'] > '2017-08-31') & (df['order_date'] < '2017-11-01') & (df['region'] == 'Central'), 'state'].unique()
            ,columns=['state'])

df_oct = states.merge(df_oct.groupby(by='state', as_index=False)['sales'].sum(), how='left', on='state')
df_sep = states.merge(df_sep.groupby(by='state', as_index=False)['sales'].sum(), how='left', on='state')

df_oct['month'] = 'October'
df_sep['month'] = 'September'
tornado_df = pd.concat([df_oct, df_sep])
tornado_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=1
        ,cols=2
        ,vertical_spacing=0
)

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Histogram(
                x=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'September', 'sales']
                ,y=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'September', 'state']
                ,histfunc='sum'
                ,orientation='h'
                ,marker_color='#D95002'
                ,name='September'
                ,opacity=0.6)
            ,row=1
            ,col=1)

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Histogram(
                x=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'October', 'sales']
                ,y=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'October', 'state']
                ,histfunc='sum'
                ,orientation='h'
                ,marker_color='#523E89'
                ,name='October'
                ,opacity=0.6)
            ,row=1
            ,col=2)    

fig_add = fig.update_xaxes(
            autorange="reversed"
            ,row=1
            ,col=1)

fig_add = fig.update_yaxes(
            visible=False
            ,row=1
            ,col=2)

fig_add.show()
```

My chart:
[image: My chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank space between the two graphs is plotly the area of the graph and the size of the subplot in concept, which can be seen in `print(fig.layout)`. So, changing that region value will produce the intended result.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=1
        ,cols=2
        ,vertical_spacing=0
)

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Histogram(
                x=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'September', 'Sales']
                ,y=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'September', 'State']
                ,histfunc='sum'
                ,orientation='h'
                ,marker_color='#D95002'
                ,name='September'
                ,opacity=0.6)
            ,row=1
            ,col=1
)

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Histogram(
                x=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'October', 'Sales']
                ,y=tornado_df.loc[tornado_df['month'] == 'October', 'State']
                ,histfunc='sum'
                ,orientation='h'
                ,marker_color='#523E89'
                ,name='October'
                ,opacity=0.6)
            ,row=1
            ,col=2
)    

fig_add = fig.update_xaxes(
            autorange="reversed"
            ,row=1
            ,col=1)

fig_add = fig.update_yaxes(
            visible=False
            ,row=1
            ,col=2)

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(domain=[0.0, 0.45]), xaxis2=dict(domain=[0.45, 0.90]))
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation='h', xanchor='center', x=0.45))

fig_add.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I need. I also set the values of plot fraction to 0.5 and added `ticklabeloverflow='hide past domain'` for first column. Now 0 doesn't look bold.

Comment: There are indeed overlapping zeros. I think your response is correct. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you have a response.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't vote for the answers yet. I will definitely do it in the future. Thanks again!)